# contextType not defined in React Function components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've converted a class to a function, however, "context" is showing not defined. I wish to obtain login variables (token, user id etc) from a file using createContext().

From the React documentation, there is no examples of contextType in a function. It also lists it as "Class.contextType", which suggests it's only available for classes. Apart from converting back to a class, is there a work around?

```
// Importing module
import AuthContext from "../context/auth-context";

// Bottom of page:
export default AuthNew;
AuthNew.contextType = AuthContext;

// Snippet of code calling for this context
.then(resData => {
        if (resData.data.login.token) {
          context.login(
            resData.data.login.token,
            resData.data.login.userId,
            resData.data.login.tokenExpiration
          );
        }
      })
```

The expected results should obtain these createContext() variables so my application can log in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`contextType` is applicable only for class component. However, if you want to use context for functional component and you are on a version **16.8.0** or above of React, you can make use of useContext hook

```
const AuthNew = () => {
   const context = useContext(AuthContext)
   ...
}
export default AuthNew;
```

However if you are on a lower version, you can make use of render prop API

```
export default (props) => {
   return <AuthContext.Consumer>
      {(context) => <AuthNew {...props} context={context} />}
   </AuthContext.Consumer>
}
```

and use it in component like `props.context`

Comment: Brilliant. I totally forgot about that. Of course, it's documented on : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html. Many thanks for your help. It now works